# Перевод отдельных элементов панели администратора

Tags: wordpress

Всем привет. Для окончания работы с сайтом на WP нужно перевести некоторые элементы панели администратора (для custom post type страниц) с английского на русский:

1) Статусы записей "Draft" и "Pending". Вроде перевели строки в post.php, но эти два статуса остаются на английском, хотя вкладки статусов вверху страницы теперь отображаются на русском.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2) Фильтры по дате и категории (тоже для страниц кастомного типа).
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

3) Выбор категории страницы кастомного типа.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Прошу подсказки, в каких файлах искать нужные строки. Всем заранее большое спасибо за любую оказанную помощь!

Comment: Вы что, модифицируете файлы ядра???

Comment: @KAGGDesign Я знаю, что хардкодить ядро сомнительное решение, так что заодно вы можете подсказать способ адекватнее :)

Comment: Скачай нормальный дистр ВП отсюда https://ru.wordpress.org/releases/ и замени всё, что ты накуролесил с ядром. Ниже в ответах все объяснения.

Answer (score 2):

Модифицировать файлы ядра (а я смотрю, вы взялись за `/wp-includes/post.php` - последнее дело. Все слетит при обновлении.

Править надо файлы .po, которые находятся в ядре, в темах, в плагинах. Для этого используется редактор [poedit](https://poedit.net/). При сохранении файла .po он создает .mo, который и надо поместить в нужные папки.

Но мне непонятно, почему вы правите ядро - оно же на 100% переведено на русский.

Файлы .po находятся:

- для ядра - в папке /wp-content/languages/ru_RU.po
- для плагинов - в папке /wp-content/languages/plugins с именами текстовый-домен-ru_RU.po
- для тем - в папке /wp-content/languages/themes  с именами текстовый-домен-ru_RU.po

Comment: Языковые файлы .po полностью русифицированы, проверял их в первую же очередь

Comment: То, что вы говорите, в природе не бывает. Как это - файлы полностью русифицированы, а вы правите post.php из ядра. Значит, файл не полный/не соответствует версии WordPress. Найдите источник проблемы, отключая плагины один за другим, и сменив тему на стандартную.

Answer (score 1):

1. Трогать файлы ядра категорически нельзя!

См https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%A7%D0%90%D0%92%D0%9E/%D0%98%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B9

2. Чтобы у юзера было всё по-русски в админке достаточно в настройках профиля юзера выбрать русский язык.
3. Перевод в ВП основан на gettext и осуществляется в лангпаках. Для самого ВП всё переведено. Плагины и темы - не все.

См https://translate.wordpress.org/locale/ru
https://make.wordpress.org/polyglots/handbook/tools/glotpress-translate-wordpress-org/
https://ru.wordpress.org/support/topic/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BD/